# Does being born between 1945 and 1965 increase your risk of Hepatitis C?

Tags: epidemiology, hepatitis

I read that being born between 1945 and 1965 increases a person's risk of Hepatitis C. What is the evidence behind that?

This is the website I found it on:
http://www.cdc.gov/features/HepatitisCTesting/

Comment: It is caused by virus. It can be a statistical association but not causal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The site you found that on is the [Centers for Disease Control and Prevention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centers_for_Disease_Control_and_Prevention). It's generally considered an authoritative source. The site states the following:

> There are high rates of Hepatitis C in people born during 1945-1965. 
>   People born during 1945 through 1965 are 5 times more likely than
>   other adults to be infected. In fact, 75% of adults with Hepatitis C
>   were born in these years. The reasons why baby boomers have the
>   highest rates of Hepatitis C are not completely understood.

In support of that statement, they include a link to [further information (PDF)](http://www.cdc.gov/knowmorehepatitis/Media/PDFs/FactSheet-Boomers.pdf). Note that in this document they mention possible reasons for the Baby Boomers to have such a high prevalence:

> Hepatitis C is primarily spread through contact with  blood from an
>   infected person. Many baby boomers  could have gotten infected from
>   contaminated blood  and blood products before widespread screening of 
>   the blood supply in 1992 and universal precautions  were adopted.
>   Others may have become infected  from injecting drugs, even if only
>   once in the past.  Still, many baby boomers do not know how or when 
>   they were infected.

Comment: It does mention possible reasons in the PDF that you linked.

Comment: @michaelpri True, but I think _possible reasons_ would be the key phrase. It's rather speculative at this point. It's an interesting statistic I was previously unaware of, particularly since I fall into the demographic.

Comment: I'm mostly trying to say you should at least mention that, but that it's not proven.

Comment: @michaelpri Done.